whats the best way to build a cryptocurrency coin on solana
i am trying to make my own coin but im confused on where i need to type in the code. for example one solana playground ? visual studio code ? ubuntu ?

Your question is a bit vague.
Any environment depending on preference will work. Use your favourite IDE (VS CODE) locally or Solana Playground.
As long as you can run Typescript projects you are good to go.
Some resources to look at

If you want to create a token using the Solana CLI -> https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/how-to-create-a-token

If you want to create a token using Metaplex helpers -> https://developers.metaplex.com/guides/javascript/how-to-create-a-solana-token

Using token-22 and web3.js -> https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/metadata-pointer



its when I'm watching YouTube videos im not sure to use the solana playground or visual studio code. i have already installed the solana CLI
